# Python-DOCX and extract numbered items from word document

Tags: python, ms-word, python-docx

I am trying to extract all headings in a Word docx document that are part of a numbered list. The numbered list has been formatted by Word such that when you press return it adds the next number. I can’t figure out how to isolate the numbered lists.

For example, in the below I would like to extract:
This is header1

This is header2

This is header2.1

Thanks.

———————————-

THIS IS A TITLE

1. This is header1

   ```
   - Some text
   ```
2. This is header2

   2.1 This is header2.1

   ```
     - Some text
   ```